# Embed a local HTML file

Tags: visual-studio, executable

How do I embed a local HTML file in an executable file???

For example I have something called war.html, how do I embed it on an executable file?

I use Visual Studio 2010 and can use different encodings like Visual Basic, Visual C++, etc.

Thank you and hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `file2c` utility, which converts a file into a definition that can be used in C source.